# Hashicorp Vault + "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out" on GKE

Tags: java, google-kubernetes-engine, hashicorp-vault, vault, gke-networking

I have a 3 node HA Hashicorp Vault deployed to GKE (tried both with Raft & Consul backends).

A pod with java app is also running in GKE.

Intermittently I see `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out` but mostly it works ok.

I've checked the Vault config, no resource quotas are configured, I've tried using just internal service instead of ingress + google lb & it's still the same.

Full log entry looks like this:

```
message:Failed executing getCredentials using address https://vault.example.com:443, open timeout 30, read timeout 30 and credentials Credentials(id=0, tenantId=1, vendorName=fortinet, values={}) @timestamp:Oct 11, 2021 @ 12:02:29.386 @version:1 logger_name:com.example.secret.service.impl.SecretStoreServiceImpl thread_name:http-nio-8080-exec-24 level:ERROR level_value:40,000 stack_trace:com.bettercloud.vault.VaultException: com.bettercloud.vault.rest.RestException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out at com.bettercloud.vault.api.Logical.read(Logical.java:118) at com.bettercloud.vault.api.Logical.read(Logical.java:74) at com.example.secret.service.impl.SecretStoreServiceImpl.getCredentials(SecretStoreServiceImpl.java:49) at com.example.secret.service.impl.SecretStoreServiceImpl.getCredentials(SecretStoreServiceImpl.java:77) at com.example.secret.controller.SecretStoreController.getCredentials(SecretStoreController.java:32) at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor46.invoke(Unknown Source) at
```

What could be the problem?

I've enabled metrics & see no problems with resources & etc & no errors in audit logs (even though there're lots of logs in audit & I may have missed smth)...

Comment: Can you `ping` host `vault.example.com` port 443 from that client host?

Comment: @user207421 ping has nothing to do with tcp port 443. telnet & curl works ok :) As I've mentioned vault works ok & most part of request from same pod go through without any problems at all so it's not a firewall issue or smth like that otherwise it wouldn't work at all.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into a similar (maybe even identical issue) of intermittent timeouts on requests to my vault server container irrespective of route (ingress, service, directly to pod).

I believe in truth my issue was running Vault in dev mode, HA (high availability) mode saw the issue subside:

https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/4406662733587-HCP-Vault-Development-tier-intermittent-request-timeout-IO-errors

But I would love to know if you have found a more creative solution as it feels terribly wasteful running such a heavy instance of vault for each development bundle when it is pretty much entirely used for app startup in my organisation.

Comment: As you can see in my question had a 3 node HA cluster, not in dev mode. Unfortunately I don't know if the issue was resolved.